# Remove Subnav Dropdown from WordPress Menu with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Ive wrote some Jquery to work on tables & Desktop which drops down with a hover or a click - it almost works great except it doesn't return (go back up) once dropped down.

Would it be correct to use a mouse leave on the following code to change display to hidden?

Here is the code I have wrote:

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $("#menu-main-menu").find('li').hover(
   function(){$(this).click();
 }).click(
 function(){

     var visibleMenu = $("ul.sub-menu:visible");
     if (visibleMenu) {
        $(visibleMenu).hide(); 
     }


    $('ul.sub-menu', this).show();
}
);
})
```

I also have this in Codepen to show better:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPbJMJ

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by changing the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $("#menu-main-menu").find('li').hover(function(){$(this).click();}).click(
 function(){

     var visibleMenu = $("ul.sub-menu:visible");
     if (visibleMenu) {
        $(visibleMenu).hide(); }

    $('ul.sub-menu', this).show();

    $("#menu-main-menu").mouseleave(function(){
    $("ul.sub-menu").hide(); 
  });
}

);
})
```

As you can see I used the mouseleave function in Jquery to remove the ul.sub-menu if the #menu-main-menu div was not selected with the mouse.

I hope this helps anyone trying to write a WordPress dropdown Sub navigation menu